# angular ng-click inside of ng-repeat always getting the same object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an array of objects that i am iterating over with an ng-repeat, and inside of that is an ng-click that sends the object from the array and sends it back to some random function in the backing controller like so:

PLUNKERR: http://plnkr.co/edit/Chvx59rRhGFwX2ImHQva

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title>Profile Screen</title>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.1/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.1/js/ionic.bundle.js" ></script>
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.1/js/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js" ></script>
<script>
    angular.module('controllers', []);

    angular.module('application', ['ionic', 'controllers','ui.router'])

    .controller('ProfileCtrl',function($scope,$ionicModal) {        

        $scope.editMode = false;            

        $scope.person = { aliases : [] };



        $scope.person.aliases.push({ firstName: 'Dave', lastName: 'Smith'});
        $scope.person.aliases.push({ firstName: 'Davey', lastName: 'Smith'});
        $scope.person.aliases.push({ firstName: 'David', lastName: 'Smith'});

        $scope.startStopEditProfile = function(status){             
            $scope.editMode = status;                       
        }

        $scope.deleteEntry = function(type,entity) {
            console.log(type,entity);
            alert("deleting "+ entity.firstName);   
        }
    })

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider      
        .state('profile',{
            url: "/profile",
            templateUrl: "profile.html",
            controller: "ProfileCtrl",          
        })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/profile');
    });
</script>    
<script type="text/ng-template" id="profile.html">
    <ion-view>
        <div class="bar bar-header">
            <div class="h1 title">My Profile</div>
            <button class="button button-stable asdf-done-button" ng-click="editMode = !editMode">{{editMode ? 'Done' : 'Edit'}}</button>
        </div>
        <ion-content style="background: #EBEBEB" class="has-header" has-bouncing="true">
            <div id="profileSection">
                <ion-item ng-class="editMode ? 'asdf-profile-row-edit' : 'asdf-profile-row-view'">                                              
                    <div class="asdf-table-row-right">
                        <label>
                            <div ng-if="editMode" ng-repeat="alias in person.aliases track by $index">
                                <span>
                                    {{$index}} -  {{alias.firstName + ' ' + alias.lastName}}
                                    <button ng-click="deleteEntry('alias',alias)" >X</button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <p ng-if="!editMode" ng-repeat="alias in person.aliases">
                                {{alias.firstName + ' ' + alias.lastName}}                                                                              
                            </p>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </ion-item>                             
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</script>
  </head>
 <body ng-app="application">
<ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
  </body>
 </html>
```

click edit in the top right,
"X"'s show up next to the names.
every time you click any "X" button, it clicks the first one and the one you actually click... its quick but you can see it if you watch it...

sorry for the externals, i slimmed it down as best as i could...

Thanks again..

Comment: a simple demo plunker ?

Comment: Provide the controller code .

Comment: I created the pluker and everything is working fine http://plnkr.co/edit/qxen8t1kWoRRZzdzBsoT. please check.

Comment: As multiple people have mentioned, what you are describing isn't reproducible with the code you have provided.  If you can create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example of the behavior, you will get a better answer than "I copied your code and it works fine".  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i understand. i will try to slim it down and reproduce outside of the application... it's kind of a pain, but if i want help i need to.. thanks for responding...

Comment: I got a slimmed down working and put up on plunker. now everyone knows that at least in regards to this issue, i am not crazy :)

Answer (score 2):

**I can reproduce your problem**, as I struggled with it for hours in a project of my own.

You are using Angular the right way. However, your problem may lie in the view itself, since your elements are inside the "label" HTML element.

Depending on the browser you use and your CSS styles, the clicks inside the elements contained in the label will propagate differently, sometimes overlapping each other. This is supposed to be an "accesibility feature",  making a wider area the user can tap with his finger to activate the control.

I have edited your plunker, and just removing the "label" elements fixes the problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The issue was because the buttons were inside of a label. It is reproducible in the OP's plunkr.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing an object . But you can get the whole properties inside
 your click event .

```js
angular.module('MyApp',[]);

function PostCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.objectArray = [
   {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
  {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
  {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
    
    ];
    $scope.onClick = function(obj){
       console.log(obj);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="PostCtrl">
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th colspan="2">Title</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="obj in objectArray">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td ng-click="onClick(obj)">
          {{obj.name}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copy your code and it work.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src='controllers.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Controller">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th colspan="2">Title</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="obj in objectArray">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td ng-click="onClick(obj)">
          {{obj.name}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('App.controllers', [])
.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.objectArray = [
        {'name':'apple'},
        {'name':'orange'},
        {'name':'pear'},
        {'name':'naartjie'}
         ];
    $scope.onClick = function(obj){
        console.log(obj);
    };
})
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('App', ['App.controllers']);
```

Code plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/rbcH47/preview

Comment: so is your answer here that there isn't a problem that needs an answer?

Comment: I think so, but i just make sure to the questioner, the code seem not wrong maybe the code in him controllers.js is not ok.